# Why is maxHeap initialisation syntax different from minHeap through priority_queue?

Tags: c++, vector, priority-queue, min-heap, max-heap

I was trying to create a minHeap using the regular syntax but found out that

maxHeap is initialised as:

```
priority_queue<int> maxHeap;
```

whereas minHeap is initailised as:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> minHeap;
```

Any idea to why is it so in C++? It could have been much easier to remember if minHeap and maxHeap were initialised using similar syntax.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd template parameters have defaults see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue  As you can't just supply the 3rd parameter (compare) you have to supply the 2nd (container type) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The priority_queue defaults to a max heap, so
`priority_queue<int>` is shorthand for `priority_queue<int, vector<int>, less<int>>`, which does indeed match the min heap syntax